# Translate a worksheet formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me to write this formula in excel VBA?

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Temp!$A$3:$A$595,1,FALSE)),A3,"0")
```

My code is getting stuck with :"syntax error"

```
Sub checkDuplitems()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const top As Integer = 3
    Dim bottom As Long
    bottom = Sheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, top).End(xlUp).row
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trash").Range("A" & top & ":A" & bottom)
        .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & top & ",Temp!$B$" & top & ":$B$" & bottom & _
                   ",1,FALSE)),A" & top & ", & '" 0" & ," '")"
        .Value = .Value
        .SortSpecial
    End With
   'Call something...
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `bottom` set to, and why? That's a very confusing calculation.

Comment: ah! the top/bottom is to identify the range for lookup in Temp sheet automatically, the IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Temp!$A$3:$A$595,1,FALSE)),A3,"0") is to hard code for testing on the excel formula

Answer (score 1):

You have a concatenation problem in the second line of the `.Formula` line.

To emulate the formula you have at the top of your question (which is wrong incidentally because you should be pointing to `$B$3:$B$595` or something like that because your look up cell `A3` should not be inside the `VLOOKUP` range).

Try this new `.Formula` line:-

```
    .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & top & ",Temp!$B$" & top & ":$B$" & bottom & _
               ",1,FALSE)),A" & top & ", " & "0)"
```

Comment: I just remove and correct the line, it works! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use `top` as both the starting row in column A and the column to get the bottom row from the Temp worksheet? The important column on the Temp worksheet is column B (i.e. 2) not C (i.e. 3).

If you are putting formula(s) into Trash!A3:A595 that reference Trash!A3:A595 then these are circular references and cannot be resolved under normal conditions. I'll put the formulas into column Z.

If you are operating with Excel 2007 or newer then I would humbly propose this alternate that uses the worksheet's [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) and does not attempt to make text out of the 0 returned value.

```
Const top As Integer = 3
Dim bottom As Long
bottom = Sheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row  '<~~change here
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("trash")
    With .Range("Z" & top, .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 25))
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & top & ", Temp!$B$" & top & ":$B$" & bottom & _
               ", 1, FALSE), 0)"  '<~~ big change here
        .Value = .Value
   End With
End With
```

It is also curious as to why the number of rows of formulas in the Trash worksheet must be governed by the number of rows of data in the Temp worksheet. I would have thought that the number of values in column A of the Trash sheet should govern how many formulas go into the Trash worksheet.

Comment: i just check i saw the unnecessary reference to get total rows in sheet("temp")  while the loop just running in sheet("trash") only. Thank